# HP Pavilion DV6000 webcam wiring

Tags: wiring, camera

How can I wire this 4 pin webcam from my old HP Pavilion DV6000?

I can't find any website that can help me with this 4 pin webcam.

As you can see it the image below, the wires black and blue are tangled together while the red and greenish or metallic like color wire are not. I don't have a multimeter right now because I don't need it in my course in college which is I.T. but we are focusing on programming.

I want to connect it to a USB cable so I can use it.

[image]

Comment: What protocol is this wire using? As there are 4 wires, with a twisted pair in there, it could be USB. With power and ground being the two not twisted wires, data being the twisted pair, which way round they are is guess work without a multi-meter. Without a schematic, multi-meter and a lot more information, there's nothing more I can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck.  The camera is indeed a USB webcam.  All you have to do is to properly wire it to a USB cable.

[Someone  here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/29160/l/laptop-webcam-to-usb-webcam-for-raspberry-pi?displayFullThread=true) has already found the connections for a similar model.  The pins and color codes match yours.

> Red: +5 : Pin 3 : USB +5V Pin 1 (Red)
>
> White: Ground : Pin 1 : USB GND Pin 4 (Black)
>
> Black: D- : Pin 5 : USB Pin 2 (White)
>
> Blue D+ : Pin 4 : USB Pin 3 (Green)

Hook those up as described and plug it in.

Your computer should recognize it as a USB device.  Find a suitable driver, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did what you've said, but the camera isn't working. Maybe the camera is dead or my usb cable is the problem. But I'll get some spare cable(if I can find one).

Comment: @AspiringTech Did you find a solution. I am having same prob

Comment: I tried it @kiranvj but it doesn't show up to my system. I already installed the driver for it and still no response from it. I'm guessing that, most of the usb cable now used 5v, and what power up the camera is 3.3v or 3v just like that. I saw a 3.3v usb cable with pin slots, but I don't have the money to buy it right now. But if you have the parts or you know how to make a chain of resistor with 2.2v then tap it to 5v cable then the output will be 3v, the right voltage for our Webcam.

Comment: @AspiringTech I figured it out, I have added it  as an answer. If you are using Windows 10, drivers should be automatically detected.

Comment: The oddity of the wire colors and the recent addition of another answer would suggest that **what really matters is the position on the connector, not the wire colors**.  There remains some possible confusion over D+/D- but getting that wrong is non-fatal and would result in false detection as a low speed device, something quite indicative of reversal of those two.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop - HP Pavilion dv 6000

[image: webcam module]

[image: Webcam pins]

You can see 4 wires coming out of web cam module.

**White, Green, Red and Black**

This is my connection to USB cable. Check continuity of the wires with a multi meter if you have it. Mine did not work as there was some wire breakage inside the wire sleeve. Had to figure it out

[image: USB and web cam connection]

This is the USB - web cam connection. Thick wires are from USB cable, thin wires are from web cam. Note that RED and BLACK are V+ and V-,  GREEN and WHITE are data lines (D+ and D- not sure which is which, but can be easily found with a multi meter). Make sure you dont have any dry solders.

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ USB wire color │  Web cam wire color  │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ RED            │ RED                  │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ BLACK          │ BLACK                │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ GREEN          │ WHITE                │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ WHITE          │ GREEN                │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Comparison with the other answer would indicate that the color coding is unreliable.  What actually matters is the **position on the connector**.   There remains some possible confusion over D+/D- but getting that wrong is non-fatal and would result in false detection as a low speed device, something quite indicative of reversal of those two.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -  Agree, the wire position thats shown in question and what I have in my webcam is slightly different, not sure why its like that, both are same laptop models though.

Comment: Unlike say electric codes, wire colors in non-interchangeable parts don't matter, and so cannot be trusted by those trying to use things in ways never intended by the manufacturer.  You're not supposed to cut and splice the wiring harness, when used as intended as a unitary component machine assembled with connectors on both ends it wouldn't matter if all the wires were chartreuse.  It's *unfortunate* that someone loaded the machine with wire colors also used by a quasi standard but put the spools in the wrong place, but also functionally irrelevant.